# How to reinstate Android app after suspended on Play console

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-console, mobile-application

We had an app which has been live in the store for more than 3 years. We have decided to revamp the UI and change the backend system. We can only release it as a separate app since the backend migration is carried out per country. I couldn't find any way to roll-out the app update, targeting countries. Last month we have released the app and it got accepted in the store. Couple of weeks later they have suspended both the apps which is insane!. We have filed an appeal for the same and its been 10 days with no response from google. We have written the migration logic from old app to the new app so we need both apps to be live at the same time to retain the customer. Once migrated we will remove the old app.

Following are the violations they have mentioned:

1. Copying content from other apps without adding any original content or value.
2. Creating multiple apps with highly similar content and user experience.

Comment: Google will reply to the appeal . but God knows when. Did you upload the second app on the same dev account as the first one.. they don't normally have objection if you upload it on the same dev account.

Comment: I have uploaded it on the same account.